# Complex integration from zero to infinity at different directions

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-integration

The problem is computing the integral expression
$$f(t)=\int_0^{\infty}\lambda^{t-1}e^{-\lambda z}d\lambda$$
where z is a complex variable with $Re(z)\ge 0$.
Is it correct to substitute $w=\lambda z$ in the integral and write down $f(t)$ as
$$f(t)=z^{-t}\int_0^{\infty}w^{t-1}e^{-w}dw$$
where w is a complex variable?

Note that while in the first integral $\lambda$ is a real variable which approaches positive infinity of real numbers, in the second integral $w$ is a complex variable and the integral is only meaningful if its value is independent from how $w$ approaches the infinity point of the extended complex plane.